# With R and XPath, how do you remove format elements such as \n and \t from the results?

Tags: html, xml, r, xpath

Using `XML` I can scrape the URL I need, but when I use `xpathSApply` on it, R returns unwanted \n and \t indicators (new lines and tabs).  Here is an example:

```
doc <- htmlTreeParse("http://www.milesstockbridge.com/offices/", useInternal = TRUE) # scrape and parse an HTML site
xpathSApply(doc, "//div[@class='info']//h3", xmlValue) 
[1] "\n\t\t\t\t\t\tBaltimore\t\t\t\t\t"     "\n\t\t\t\t\t\tCambridge\t\t\t\t\t"     "\n\t\t\t\t\t\tEaston\t\t\t\t\t"        "\n\t\t\t\t\t\tFrederick\t\t\t\t\t"    
[5] "\n\t\t\t\t\t\tRockville\t\t\t\t\t"     "\n\t\t\t\t\t\tTowson\t\t\t\t\t"        "\n\t\t\t\t\t\tTysons Corner\t\t\t\t\t" "\n\t\t\t\t\t\tWashington\t\t\t\t\t"
```

As explained in this question, regex functions can easily remove the unwanted format elements
[how to delete the \n\t\t\t in the result from website data collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959968/how-to-delete-the-n-t-t-t-in-the-result-from-website-data-collection/21960114#21960114][1]) but I would rather xpath do the work first, if possible (I have hundreds of these to parse).

Also, there are functions such as `translate`, apparently, as in this question:
[Using the Translate function to remove newline characters in xml, but how do I ignore certain tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672611/using-the-translate-function-to-remove-newline-characters-in-xml-but-how-do-i-i]][2]) as well as `strip()` that I saw in a Python question.  I do not know which are available when using R and xpath.

It may be that a `text()` function helps, but I do not know how to include it in my xpathSApply expression.  Likewise with `normalize-space()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just want the `trim = TRUE` argument in your `xmlValue()` call.

```
> xpathSApply(doc, "//div[@class='info']//h3", xmlValue, trim = TRUE) 
#[1] "Baltimore"     "Cambridge"     "Easton"       
#[4] "Frederick"     "Rockville"     "Towson"       
#[7] "Tysons Corner" "Washington"
```

Comment: Ah, you were very kind, @Richard Scriven, not to needle me a bit about not reading the arguments to xpathSApply.  If I may ask, what have I learned between a return value of "list()" and "Null"?

Comment: I believe a `list()` result means you got an empty mode set.  `NULL` is the default return for nothing found.  Don't quote me on that though, I'm still learning too. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25213983/explanation-of-how-this-complex-function-works) has a very good explanation of an easy method.

Comment: The other question about findLinks certainly has a wonderful explanation of that function.  As to list() vs. NULL, at least the former suggests to me I am in the ballpark, whereas NULL is striking out.  Firebug goes a long way, but I have challenges when modes come between my [@class='offices'] for example and the actual city I seek.

Comment: If you're trying to figure out the right selector to use, try http://selectorgadget.com/